# Run with Code Coverage doesn't appear in Android Studio 1.5.1 for basic Empty Activity Project for Instrumentation tests

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio

I created a basic Android Project in Android Studio 1.5.1 on Mac OS X. I chose the Empty Activity template. By default Android Studio provides one example Unit Test and one example Android Instrumentation Test.

I am able to run regular Unit Test with Code coverage. However when I set the build variant to "Android Instrumentation Tests" and right click on java folder under androidTest I don't get the "Run 'All Tests' with Coverage" option. What is the reason for this?

Also in another project which was created using Android Studio 1.2.1, I get the "Run 'All Tests' with Coverage" in the upgraded Android Studio 1.5.1 but it fails with error message:

```
!!! JUnit version 3.8 or later expected:


java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
    at junit.runner.BaseTestRunner.<init>(BaseTestRunner.java:5)
    at junit.textui.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:54)
    at junit.textui.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:48)
    at junit.textui.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:41)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.junitVersionChecks(JUnitStarter.java:191)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.canWorkWithJUnitVersion(JUnitStarter.java:174)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

I have tried to fix this by changing the order of the dependencies in "app.iml" file. But haven't managed to run the Instrumentation Tests with Coverage. This was the reason I tried to upgrade the Android Studio from 1.2.1 to 1.5.1.

Has anybody successfully run Android Instrumentation Tests with Code Coverage using Android Studio 1.5.1? If yes, can you please explain the process involved.